# color guess comparison of strings

Tags: javascript

I am working on this code my code is correct in half portion but I have some problem in check _guess function only. And I tried different techniques but I could not find it. And as I am a beginner and I don't know about JavaScript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script >
    var colors =['blue','cyan','gold','gey','green','magenta','orange','red','white','yellow'];
    var target;
    var count = 0;
    var finished = false;
    var guess_input;

    function do_game(){
        target = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        while (check_guess()) {
            guess_input_text = prompt("i am thinking of color + colors" +"which color i am random");
            guess_input = parseInt(guess_input_text);
            count += 1;
            finished = check_guess(guess_input);
        }
    }

    function check_guess( guess_input){
        if (colors.indexOf(guess_input) === 0) {
            alert("Sorry.  I don't recognize your color. \n\n Please try again");
            return false;
        }
        if (guess_input < target) {
            alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct. \n\n Hint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine");
            return false;
        }
        if (guess_input > target) {
            alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct. \n\n Hint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            elem_body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            elem_body.style.background = colors[target];
            alert("You are right! You took " + count + " guesses!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fast reading, in your check_guess function, your first check would not produce the expected output, as indexOf returns -1 if it doesn't find the desired value in your colors array (if it returns 0, then it is at index 0) you should then check that it equals -1. Also, why do you return false if the player's guess if the right one, to return true just after your else condition ? (which would never be evaluated as you're always returning false before)

Comment: In your `check_guess()` function, You are always returning `false` regardless of what is `guess_input`. So in the `else` section you have to use `return true` instead of `return false`. And then in your `do_game()` you have to use `while (!finished) {` instead of `while (check_guess()) {`

Comment: Tip: instead of getting `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`, you can just use `document.body`.